# what should go into the parentheses for def?

Tags: python, tkinter, function

I am making a program for my GCSE  computing program . This program is for a primary school.
Its a test with multiplication questions and it suppose to generate a final score at the end

I used tkinter to create the program and its all fine but when I created a def to generate the score it doesn't work.when I run my program it's fine but I fill the quiz and click on the finish button it starts loading and gives me an error that the program can not run.
I think the problem is from the def function and I think I need to add something in between the parentheses but I don't know what.

here is my whole program:

```
from tkinter import*
from random import*



n1= randint(1,10)
n2= randint(1,10)
ques1 = n1, "x", n2, "="
c1= n1*n2

n1= randint(1,10)
n2= randint(1,10)
ques2 = n1, "x", n2, "="
c2= n1*n2

n1= randint(1,10)
n2= randint(1,10)
ques3 = n1, "x", n2, "="
c3= n1*n2

n1= randint(1,10)
n2= randint(1,10)
ques4 = n1, "x", n2, "="
c4= n1*n2

#window
window = Tk()
window.geometry("280x450")
window.title("quiz")
window.configure(background='yellow')

score = 0
def save(score):

    while True:
        if c1==ans1:
            score= score +1
            pass
        else:
            pass

        if c2==ans2:
            score = score+1
            pass
        else:
            pass

        if c3==ans3:
            score = score+1
            pass
        else:
            pass

        if c4==ans4:
            score = score+1
            fscore.set(score)
        else:
        fscore.set(score)


#frame
frame = Frame(window)
frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

#variables
ans1 = StringVar()
ans2 = StringVar()
ans3 = StringVar()
ans4 = StringVar()
fscore = StringVar()

#labels
q1 = Label(window,text = ques1, height = 3, bg = 'yellow')
q1.grid(row = 1,column=0)

q2 = Label(window,text = ques2, height = 3, bg = 'yellow')
q2.grid(row = 2,column=0)

q3 = Label(window,text = ques3, height = 3, bg = 'yellow')
q3.grid(row = 3,column=0)

q4 = Label(window,text = ques4, height = 3, bg = 'yellow')
q4.grid(row = 4,column=0)

#entrys
q1_entry = Entry(window, width = 6, textvariable = ans1)
q1_entry.grid(row = 1,column=1)

q2_entry = Entry(window, width = 6, textvariable = ans2)
q2_entry.grid(row = 2,column=1)

q3_entry = Entry(window, width = 6, textvariable = ans3)
q3_entry.grid(row = 3,column=1)

q4_entry = Entry(window, width = 6, textvariable = ans4)
q4_entry.grid(row = 4,column=1)

#buttons

finish = Button(window, width = 5, text = "finish",command= save)
finish.grid(row = 5,column=0)

q4 = Label(window,textvariable =fscore)
q4.grid(row = 5,column=1)
```

Comment: Change it to `def save(): score= 0`. Oh, and remove the `while`.

Comment: And all the `else: pass` blocks, they're utterly pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the problems I see:

**Save expects parameters but receives none**

The way you normally define and call functions in Python is like this:

```
def myFunction( param1, param2 ) :
    print( "param1: {}, param2: {}".format( param1, param2 )

myFunction( 10, named_param="hello" ) # Outputs "param1: 10, param2: hello"
```

You pass into the function a set of parameters that are local to that function. When the function is called, the parameters are set, and when the function returns, the parameters are freed up. Parameters allow you to change how a function operates between calls.

This is how you defined your `save` function:

```
score = 0
def save( score ) :
    ...
```

Here you have defined a variable `score` before defining the function. When you give your `save` function a `score` parameter, it effectively hides the original `score` variable. Now whenever you access `score` from inside `save`, you're accessing the local variable that is defined only while the function is running.

The problem is that it expects whatever calls it to give it a value for `score`. It does not associate its parameter `score` with the variable you defined. For all intensive purposes, they are separate objects. What you want to do, rather than give your function a parameter, is this:

```
def save() :
    score = 0
```

Here we define a local variable called `score` inside the `save` function. This variable is defined inside the function and is destroyed when the function returns, like a parameter, but it is always initialized to 0. Additionally, we don't have to tell the function what the value of `score` is. It already knows that score starts at 0.

Why does the earlier implementation give us an error? `tkinter.Button`'s command parameter takes a function variable, not a function call. The way it calls your function is out of your control and it does not pass any arguments to the function. There are ways to get around this limitation, but you don't need to, because the initial value of `score` shouldn't change between calls.

**Infinite loop in save function never ends**

`while True:` is an infinite loop. Unless explicitly ended with a `break`, `return`, or other statement that terminates execution, it'll continue to run forever without executing any other part of your code.

You do not need the `while True:` line for your code to execute. I recommend removing it because you don't need to loop over anything in the function.

**Unnecessary else and pass statements**

You do not need to specify an `else` condition for every `if` statement. You also don't need to use `pass` at the end of every `if` statement. The way you should be writing your statements is as such:

```
if c1 == ans1:
    score = score + 1
```

`pass` does nothing. It's used mostly to fill space where a statement is expected but not given, for example, as a placeholder in a function you have yet to write. `else` is called when an `if` statement evaluates to `False` and is not required. Unless you want to do something for all other cases, don't just add an `else` block to an `if` statement.

You can see one of the problems this introduces here:

```
    if c4==ans4:
        score = score+1
        fscore.set(score)
    else:
        fscore.set(score)
```

Instead of writing this block like this, you could write it like this:

```
    if c4==ans4:
        score = score+1
    fscore.set(score)
```

`fscore.set` will always be called here. Try to attempt to minimize code and consolidate your conditions. In the future, if you want the function to do more once it's gotten the player's score, it'll make it easier to add on to the end of the function rather than keeping track of all control paths and making sure everything acts the same way.

**Use get to get the actual values of your entries**

The way your program is set up, you will never score points, because you're never accessing the actual text values of your entry fields. Look at this line:

```
if c1==ans1:
```

While you think this is comparing the text value of `ans1` to `c1`, what it's doing is comparing the TK variable to a number, which will always be False. You need to get the value of the entry and then convert it to a number (from a string) in order to get the result you want:

```
if c1==int(ans1.get()):
```

Why do we need to use the `get` method? Because ans1 holds the TextVariable object. There's a lot of things that it does, but because of the way it's implemented, you have to extract the value from it. Otherwise you're trying to compare objects of two different types, which won't work.

Why do we need to use the `int` function? Because `c1` is an integer, but `ans1.get()` gives us a string. In Python, you have to convert a string to its integer value for the comparison to be valid. In other words, `10 != "10"`.

Comment: I was stuck in this program for long time. thank you very very much